# Loop Insert Date a daily commit day to day timestamp ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

im executing query in oracle. i need insert data everyday commit in looping like this :

```
DECLARE
   start_date      NUMBER;
   end_date        NUMBER;
   business_date   VARCHAR2 (8);
BEGIN
   start_date := TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2017-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')));
   end_date := TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd')));
   FOR cur_r IN start_date .. end_date
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO file_backup
         SELECT *
           FROM file_core
          WHERE TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (datecreated, 'yyyy-MM-dd')))>=start_date+cur_r
            AND TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (datecreated, 'yyyy-MM-dd')))<=end_date;
            COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I dunt know error this script .. please help me .. btw i newbie in oracle sorry ..

Comment: What is the data type of column `datecreated`?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. Is it not that your insert  statements equivalent to inserting all records from file_core between `start_date` and `end_date`  at once?

Comment: I need a daily commit day to day for log ... how ?

Comment: Why does it matter to you if you run commit after inserting  daily set of logs or all at once?  At the end, all the day's records for the dates in range should  be committed to the database, isn't it?

Comment: To much data in this table .. so i need commit step by step a day ..

Comment: Do you actually have a problem if you try to do it in one go, or are you just guessing/assuming that it needs to be in a loop? How many rows are going to be inserted overall? What error do you get if you try to do it all one transaction?

Comment: between 10 -11 milion data per day and this risk cause database transactional..

Comment: Have you by any chance tried to make use of a `Forall` statement with `Limit` clause here or elsewhere?

Comment: no .. i just need limit day per day in this script ..

Comment: btw -Wernfried .. datecreated is timestamp .

Comment: What about CTAS approach?

Comment: sorry i dunt know CTAS ..  im just use oracle for 3 months..

Comment: For future reference, please tell us the business logic you're trying to implement, ideally illustrated with some sample data and desired outcome. This would be a lot easier for us to understand what you are trying to do. Don't just post a piece of shonky code and expect us to reverse engineer your business rules from it.

Comment: okay guys .. sorry before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @boneist pointed out, your manipulation using numbers isn't going to work. You should keep the data type as it is and compare with values of the same data type.

Assuming you have a legitimate need to do this in a loop you *could* do something like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    select date '2017-01-01' + level -1 as this_date
    from dual
    connect by level <= date '2018-01-01' - date '2017-01-01'
  )
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO file_backup
      SELECT *
        FROM file_core
       WHERE datecreated >= r.this_date
         AND datecreated < r.this_date + 1;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or if the data type is actually a timestamp rather than a date as suggested in a comment, something like:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    select timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      + (level -1) * interval '1' day as this_timestamp
    from dual
    connect by level <= extract(day from timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
      - timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
  )
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO file_backup
      SELECT *
        FROM file_core
       WHERE datecreated >= r.this_timestamp
         AND datecreated < r.this_timestamp + interval '1' day;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

... though you might want to work on the condition for the connect-by query, e.g.

```
  FOR r IN (
    select timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      + numtodsinterval(level -1, 'DAY') as this_timestamp
    from dual
    connect by timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      + numtodsinterval(level -1, 'DAY') < timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
  )
  LOOP
  ...
```

or as @boneist suggested in a comment, with a simpler loop:

```
BEGIN
  FOR num_days in 0..(date '2018-01-01' - date '2017-01-01' - 1)
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO file_backup
      SELECT *
        FROM file_core
       WHERE datecreated >= timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
               + numtodsinterval(num_days, 'DAY')
         AND datecreated < timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
               + numtodsinterval(num_days + 1, 'DAY');
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The main problem with this approach is restartability. If there is an error part way through the loop you can't just re-run it, as you'd be inserting duplicates.

Multiple inserts and commits are also less efficient that a single insert, or even multiple inserts and a single commit. If you don't have enough undo space to allow a single transaction to do all the work you need you should be fixing the database configuration to allow that, rather than working around it and potentially compromising data integrity.

> i need backup this table . and insert only 2 month in new table

That sounds like you need to partition the table by month and use partition swaps to shift old months from the live to the backup table, perhaps. Partitioning costs more but if you have those data volumes it may be justified.

Failing that you could consider renaming your current table to backup, recreating your original table, and just copying the two months' worth of data you want to keep back to that. But that's a one-off thing, you still have the ongoing problem of ageing records out of the main table and into backup. And it has its own issues with dependencies, constraints, etc.

Comment: Please pay attention to everyone's comments and suggestions though... this may work but isn't necessarily the best approach to the real issue you're facing.

Comment: @AlexPoole is the cursor necessary? Wouldn't it be more efficient to do something like `for i in 0 .. num_days loop .... where datecreated >= start_date + i and ...`, i.e. skipping the extra context switches between sql and pl/sql?

Comment: @Boneist - yes, that would be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any loop and you should skip all these `TO_CHAR`, `TO_NUMBER`, `TO_DATE` conversions. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO file_backup
SELECT *
FROM file_core
WHERE datecreated BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-01';
```

Perhaps `datecreated` has time values different to `00:00:00`, in this case you should run

```
INSERT INTO file_backup
SELECT *
FROM file_core
WHERE TRUNC(datecreated) BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-01';
```

or in case `datecreated` is a VARCHAR2 data type rather than `DATE` run

```
INSERT INTO file_backup
SELECT *
FROM file_core
WHERE TO_DATE(datecreated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-01';
```

Comment: cause this big data guys .. table to much data so i need insert day per day

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `datecreated` column is of data type `DATE` and you only want one copy of the rows of the table then you do not need PL/SQL:

```
INSERT INTO file_backup
  SELECT *
  FROM file_core
  WHERE datecreated BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-01';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: cause this big data guys .. table to much data so i need insert day per day

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DATE` literal to set the start_date and end_date and use a `loop` like this.

```
DECLARE
   start_date      NUMBER;
   end_date        NUMBER;
BEGIN
   start_date := DATE '2017-01-01';
   end_date   := DATE '2018-01-01';

   FOR cur_r IN 0 .. (end_date - start_date)
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO file_backup
         SELECT *
           FROM file_core
          WHERE  TRUNC (datecreated) = start_date + cur_r;

   COMMIT;                              
   END LOOP;

 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you do it using a simple INSERT, such as

```
INSERT INTO file_backup
   SELECT *
     FROM file_core
    WHERE datecreated BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2018-01-01';
```

If you're just practicing PL/SQL and loops, well, remove COMMIT out of the LOOP. Both START and END_DATE should be "converted" to a number using a proper format mask (i.e. yyyymmdd). FOR loop's index should go from 1 to a difference between END and START_DATE.

**[EDITED, after reading MT0's comment]**

**[EDITED #2, after reading some more comments]**

Bah, my code is rubbish, should've thought about what I'm doing. Basically, if I meant to write it properly, it would have looked like @Kaushik Nayak's, and there's really no point in doing it twice.

Comment: The PL/SQL script will insert rows where `datecreated = end_date` on every iteration of the loop creating duplicate rows in the `file_backup` table.

Comment: There is no need to convert the dates to a number: 20170101 + 40 = 20170141, which is a) not the same as 40 days after 1st Jan 2017 and b) never going to be returned by `to_number(<date>, 'yyyymmdd')` since no month has 41 days in it! Keeping things in DATE datatype is much more meaningful both logically and to the optimizer. Especially if there's an index on the datecreated column.

Comment: @robieyogiansyah "too much data so I need to insert day by day" ... why? Do you run out of undo tablespace or something when you run the single insert statement?

Comment: Yesss ,., run out tablespace .. so i need backup this table . and insert only 2 month in new table.

Comment: can u help me fix this script .. please i stack in 3 day .

Comment: -Littlefoot Can u help me if datecreated is timestamp . ?

Comment: I'd just truncate it (i.e. remove time component) and use date only.

Comment: @Boneist, thank you; sorry for posting stupidities all around.

Comment: @Littlefoot don't worry about it. Every day's a learning day!